# Using RxJava for request response layer with WebSockets

Tags: java, rx-java, java-websocket

I'm trying to implement a request -> response layer on top of websockets in Java. I recently stumbled across `RxJava`, which seems like a nice library to use for this. Down below is my current approach for handling the request response flow (unimportant code omitted for readability)

```java
public class SimpleServer extends WebSocketServer {
  Gson gson = new Gson();
  Map<String, Function<JsonObject, Void>> requests = new HashMap<>();

  private static int count = 0;

  public SimpleServer(InetSocketAddress address) {
    super(address);
  }

  @Override
  public void onMessage(WebSocket conn, String message) {
    String type = ...;
    JsonObject payload = ...;
    if (type.equals("response")) {
      Request request = requests.get(requestId).apply(payload);
    }
  }

  public Single<JsonObject> request(String action) {
    requests.put(Integer.toString(count++), response -> {
      source.onSuccess(response);
      return null;
    });
    broadcast(...);
  }
}
```

Is this a viable solution or is there a better way?
 I was thinking if there was a way to use `RxJava` for both ways, i.e. the request would listen to an "onMessage" observable or something along those lines.
All help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use RxJava for communication in both ways. Let's start with a simpler one – receiving messages. I recommend you use [`BehaviorRelay`](https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxRelay) what behaves both like `Observer` and `Consumer`. You can both listen for emitted values and produce values – messages in our case. A simple implementation might look like this:

```java
public class SimpleServer extends WebSocketServer {
    private BehaviorRelay<String> receivedMessages = BehaviorRelay.create();

    public SimpleServer(InetSocketAddress address) {
        super(address);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessage(WebSocket conn, String message) {
        receivedMessages.accept(message); // "sends" value to the relay
    }

    public Observable<String> getReceivedMessagesRx() {
        return receivedMessages.hide(); // Cast Relay to Observable
    }

    //...
```

You can now call function `getReceivedMessagesRx()` and subscribe for incoming messages.

Now the more interesting part – sending messages. Let's assume, you have some Observable, what produces messages you want to send:

```java
    // ...

    private Disposable senderDisposable = Disposables.disposed(); // (1)

    public void setMessagesSender(Observable<String> messagesToSend) { // (2)
        senderDisposable = messagesToSend.subscribe(message -> { 
            broadcast(message);
        }, throwable -> {
            // handle broadcast error 
        });
    }

    public void clear() { // (3)
        senderDisposable.dispose(); 
    }
}
```

What happens here:

1. Create `Disposable` which holds a reference to running observer of the messages to be sent.
2. Subscribe to passed `Observable` what emits every time you want to send a message. This function is meant to be called only once. If you want to call it multiple times, handle the disposal of previous sender or use `CompositeDisposable` to store multiple disposables.
3. When you are done working with your server, do not forget to dispose messages sender.